# How to find out the generation of my Intel Xeon Gold 6130 processor?

Tags: processor, cluster-computing, intel

me and some colleauges want to use cluster-computing to do fast deep learning inference. We thought about using OpenVINO by intel as to do so. However, OpenVINO requires 6th to 8th generation Intel Core or Intel Xeon processors.

Our processors are:
Intel Xeon Gold 6130

Is it correct that the second digit is the generation? I thought the Xeon Gold 6130 was released in Q3 2017, so I am surprised how it can be 1st generation...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HW Recs! In general, we don't answer technical support questions as that is under the scope of Super User. I believe that your processor is 6th generation (though I am not familiar with Xeon series) as the first digit usually denotes the generation. See official [Intel Letter Codes guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Intel Processor naming**

On Desktop and Mobile processors, the first digit after the brand modifier is the generation, as explained [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html)

[image: Desktop processor naming]

On Server and Workstation, it is the second digit that counts, as said [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers-data-center.html)

[image]

**OpenVINO requirements**

What Intel says [on their webpage](https://software.intel.com/en-us/openvino-toolkit/documentation/system-requirements) the requirements are is:

> 6th to 8th generation Intel® Core™ and Intel® Xeon® processors

That means, you car use Intel Core processor, but it has to be from the 6th to 8th generation, or you could use any Xeon processor

**Conclusion**

Your CPU is good to go.